# Mysql change column name from "group" to "group_code"

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlcommand

I have set a column name to "group", which turned out to be a reserved word. Now I try to change the name to "group_code", but I get an error. I try:

```
ALTER TABLE task_values CHANGE group group_code VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE task_values CHANGE 'group' group_code VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL;
```

but both fail, I get "No such element" error. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use backticks around `group` which, as you said, is a **mysql reserved keyword**

```
ALTER TABLE task_values CHANGE `group` group_code VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL;
```